# Mathematica never stop when running Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]

Tags: compile, kernel-startup, ccompilerdriver

I am using Mathematica 12.2. I found that running

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
```

kind of freezes my Mathematica, it just never stop. Alt+. can not abort it either.

[image]

and currently, **all my Compile function with CompilationTarget->"C" also freezes.**

it is just happened today!! There was no problem running this before, because I always put this line in my init.m. What is wrong with my Mathematica? How to fix it?

Comment: Can't reproduce in 12.2 on Ubuntu. Perhaps, you can try to [reset](https://support.wolfram.com/12464)/reinstall WM.

Comment: @I.M Thank you so much for comment. I did that just now. It does not work.

Comment: The auto-update of paclets may make the kernel freeze when the internet is poor. Try it again after having disabled the internet.

Comment: @rnotlnglgq Thank you for comment. But I do not think this the route of cause. The internet connection is fine. Paclets downloading is fine too.

Comment: @matheorem what did Wolfram tech support say when you reported this?

Comment: @JasonB. Well, I did not report this. That is why I made this post and add a bounty :)

Comment: Can you post the output from `PacletInformation["CCompilerDriver"]`?

Comment: @JasonB. This is the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/p08Rw.png

Comment: @JasonB. Here is the latest news: I just installed version 13. The problem is the same. PacletInformation is the same except that the "location" is version 13 folder  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwvpt.png

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue myself by accident.

I usually put Needs["CCompilerDriver`"] in init.m file, and I found even if I closed the frozen Mathematica, I can not delete the init.m file. Then I found this file is locked by cmd.exe and wsl.exe. I realized that I intentionally made a setting in widnows regedit so that cmd.exe will automatically enter sublinux bash mode. Somehow, Mathematica needs to run cmd.exe when executing Needs function. So I restore the default cmd.exe behaviour. Now everything is fine.